# Error "asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag:crypto\asn1\tasn_dec.c:1188" when creating certificate.pem and privatekey.pem using pfx certificate

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I get the following errors when creating certificate.pem and privatekey.pem using certificate your_certificate.pfx

```
C:\Users\abc\Desktop>openssl pkcs12 -in your_certificate.pfx -clcerts -nokeys -out certificate.pem
54240000:error:068000A8:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag:crypto\asn1\tasn_dec.c:1188:
54240000:error:0688010A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_item_embed_d2i:nested asn1 error:crypto\asn1\tasn_dec.c:349:Type=PKCS12

C:\Users\abc\Desktop>openssl pkcs12 -in your_certificate.pfx -nocerts -nodes -out privatekey.pem
68360000:error:068000A8:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag:crypto\asn1\tasn_dec.c:1188:
68360000:error:0688010A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_item_embed_d2i:nested asn1 error:crypto\asn1\tasn_dec.c:349:Type=PKCS12
```

Comment: Well we can't swing a magic wand and make your problems disappear. It would be helpful if you provided a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).